# get request from Flutter to node js using dio error

Tags: node.js, flutter, dart

I am working on a flutter simple app with login functionality using node js as a backend. Everything is working fine in Postman but while using dio package in Flutter, im getting the following error:
error: 'Http status error [400]',
message: 'Can't authorize user'

Note: As i put if condition for checking email & password are not provided in node js logIn method, so it is giving that can't authorize user. It means nodejs is not getting the email & password, that I'm sending using dio in flutter.

here is how im doing login method in node:

```
exports.logIn = async (req, res) => {
try {
const { email, password } = req.body;

if (!email || !password) {
  return res.status(400).json({
    error: true,
    message: "Cannot authorize user.",
  });
}

//1. Find if any account with that email exists in DB
const user = await User.findOne({ email: email });

// NOT FOUND - Throw error
if (!user) {
  return res.status(404).json({
    error: true,
    message: "Account not found",
  });
}

//2. Throw error if account is not activated
if (!user.active) {
  return res.status(400).json({
    error: true,
    message: "You must verify your email to activate your account",
  });
}

//3. Verify the password is valid
const isValid = await User.comparePasswords(password, user.password);

if (!isValid) {
  return res.status(400).json({
    error: true,
    message: "Invalid credentials",
  });
}
await user.save();

//Success
return res.send({
  success: true,
  message: "User logged in successfully",
});
} catch (err) {
console.error("Login error", err);
return res.status(500).json({
  error: true,
  message: "Couldn't login. Please try again later.",
});
}
};
```

here is how im doing login method in Flutter using dio:

```
class AuthServices {
Dio dio = Dio();
String baseUrl = 'https://node-login-flutter.herokuapp.com/user/login';

logIn(email, password) async {
try {
  return await dio.get(
    baseUrl,
    queryParameters: {'email': email, 'password': password},
    options: Options(
      contentType: Headers.formUrlEncodedContentType,
    ),
    
  );
  } on DioError catch (e) {
  Fluttertoast.showToast(
      msg: e.response.data['message'],
      toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
      gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
      timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      textColor: Colors.white,
      fontSize: 16.0);
     }
  }
}
```

Here is Postman's successful result:
[image]

Comment: ìf you pass your credentials as static here, does it work? `queryParameters: {'email': email, 'password': password}`

Comment: @ChrisPi I did that too, still the same error. I think something is wrong with contentType

Comment: yes maybe.. Other endpoints like signup are working fine. Is queryParameters in dio.get used to pass the data or what?

Comment: I've researched again, lookup :)

Answer (score 0):

"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" is a POST related method. Therefore its maybe a bug in POSTMAN to respond a proper result.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST

```
class AuthServices {
  Dio dio = Dio();
  String baseUrl = 'https://node-login-flutter.herokuapp.com/user/login';
  logIn(email, password) async {
    try {
      final f = await http.post(baseUrl, headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      }, body: {
        'email': "arjun.mahar138@gmail.com",
        'password': "arjunarjun"
      });
      print("THE RESULT: ${f.body.toString()}");
      return f;
      // return await dio.post(baseUrl,
      //     data: {'email': "arjun.mahar138@gmail.com", 'password': "arjunarjun"},
      //     options: Options(contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      print("$e");
    }
  }
```

This should work if you write a POST handling on your API